# What kind of sensor could this be? (Also recommended sensor for detecting the entry of vehicles)

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, pir

[image: The sensor in question]

Any idea which sensor this might be? It is being used to detect the presence of a cold and ferrous vehicle, in this case a truck passing by, with minimum speed 1km/h and max speed 5 km/h.

Also would like recommendations on sensing the presence of large vehicles. Reading distance can be as low as 0.5m and maximum 10m. I've narrowed it down to photoelectric or PIR. Is there a better way for this? I'd prefer to have a method with both the emitter and receiver in the same casing. (Rules out photoelectric thru beam)

Comment: When you say you want to detect "the presence of large vehicles"...is it **allowed** to not detect small vehicles or is it **required** to not detect small vehicles? What is the range of velocity of the vehicles? Are they certain to be hot? What are your constraints on where the sensor can be mounted with respect to the vehicle?

Comment: cars are fine too. Nothing smaller than a car. Basically whenever a large ferrous object is within the reading range, atleast min 6 sqm in area. Considering the application is mainly to detect trucks, a long reading range means i can mount it on top of the structure, which is roughly 4.5m high. (So need atleast 3m reading range to read a small hatchback or sedan). If range is low, then i need to mount it on a separate frame where it can be closer to the vehicle

Comment: for the sensor in the picture, not sure what the limitation is, the function is to detect vehicles in general, velocity is around 2kmh max, No, they can be cold also.

Comment: A mass sensor on / under the surface.

Comment: You need to edit all your information into the question. Be sure to include the words "ferrous" and "cold". List minimum and maximum velocity, not "around". What is the **shape** of the 6 square meter area? The information you have added so far rules out PIR. Again, when you say "nothing smaller than a car" do mean that it **must not** detect anything smaller than a car? If so, how big is the smallest car you want to detect?

Comment: Alright. Consider a vehicle with minimum dimensions 4 x 1.7 x 1.4 m (lxbxh) which is around 6 sqm horizontal surface area. It should not detect anything smaller than this. Since the object is a vehicle, it will always be ferrous. Minimum velocity is 1 km/h, with maximum velocity will be 5 km/h

Comment: [how small a car](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/93/dc/8c/93dc8c82176cda1547e805b40808ff2d.jpg)?

Comment: Magnetic loop @ f ? is best way

Comment: As pointed out already, your specifications need to be in the question, not buried in the comments where they will be missed. You might also add in why you're not using an inductive loop buried in the ground. These are common and reliable.

Comment: poor installation ... no drip loop in the cable .... could be ok if it never rains